# How can I format selected java code in sublime text .txt file?

Tags: java, sublime-text-2, code

Is there any extension or technique for formatting java code in sublime text?

For example,

**I have this code:**

```
    static void test() 
{
        Pair<Integer, Integer>[] intPairArr = new Pair<Integer, Integer>[10]; // error
         addElements(intPairArr);
        Pair<Integer, Integer> pair = intPairArr[1];
           Integer i = pair.getFirst();
        pair.setSecond(i);
        }
```

**I want this formatted code:**

```
static void test() {
    Pair<Integer, Integer>[] intPairArr = new Pair<Integer, Integer>[10]; // error
    addElements(intPairArr);
    Pair<Integer, Integer> pair = intPairArr[1];
    Integer i = pair.getFirst();
    pair.setSecond(i);
}
```

I don't want to use an IDE for formatting code in a sublime text .txt file. Basically I want to select a snippet Java code in .txt file and format it properly.

1. I tried [CodeFormatter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CodeFormatter) plugin for Sublime Text.I get the following
   error:

   ```
   Formatter for this type(plain text) not found
   ```
2. I tried **Edit > Line > Reindent** but this technique is waste of time.
3. I tried [Sublime​AStyle​Formatter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeAStyleFormatter) plugin for Sublime
   Text, as well.When I select my code and press Ctrl+K
   for formatting my current selection, it doesn't work.

How can I format selected java code in a sublime text .txt file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest that you use [CoolFormatter.](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CoolFormat) According to the description, it is:

A Sublime Text plugin for Source Code Formatter. CoolFormat Source Code Formatter is a code formatter for C\C++\C#\CSS \HTML\Java\JavaScript\JSON\Objective-C\PHP\SQL\XML files.

I think your code is in Java, so this would work

The keybindings are:

- **Format entire file:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>
- **Format selected text:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

Comment: Thank you.This program works on java code in the .java file but it doesn't work on java code in the .txt file.

Comment: I convert all my notes .java file with  Extension Changer  and now I can format it,thanks

Comment: @my-lord you can use the command palette shortcut Set Syntax: java to temporarily change the syntax of your text files and then use CoolFormat to format the code and save it. This won't require you to change the extension of all your text files.